# spring session accessible by only one IP?

Tags: java, spring, session

I have a small spring MVC-app with session, with also some small amount of REST methods.
If I copy the JSESSIONID and use it with a 'curl'-command I'm able to access the rest methods from a different computer with a different IP, and thus 'faking' a session.

Is there a way to "bind" a session to one IP-address?

Comment: Worth remembering that the same client could be visible on multiple IP addresses legitimately (e.g. behind load balancing proxies)

Comment: Yes, that discussion has been made, and we are aware of the potential problem.

Comment: Just store the remote address in your session after the login and check it.

Comment: Bart, thanks, easy done and "affordable" :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read through `Session Fixation Attack Protection` in the [Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html), where it is written, that you can configure that inside the `session-management` tag

```
<session-mangagement session-fixation-protection="migrateSession|none|newSession">
```

- **migrateSession** - creates a new session and copies the existing session attributes to the new session. This is the default.
- **none** - Don't do anything. The original session will be retained.
- **newSession** - Create a new "clean" session, without copying the existing session data.

a session will be *fixed* to a set of variables like browser agent, IP. So in your case the browser agent of curl will not match and the provided sessionid will be of no use

Comment: Nice one! Maybe "newSession" is an acceptable solution nonetheless, I'll give it a shot - thanks :-)

Comment: Session fixation protection strategy in Spring Security does **not** *fix* a session IP or user agent. What it does is it _may_ (for `migrateSession` and `newSession` renew session ID (by destroying an existing session and creating a new one) on successful login. This is done to prevent a session fixation attack: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation for which, to work, session ID before login and after login have to be the same. If the ID changes, session fixation won't work.

Comment: I think, this is not the answer to the question. He made a test and show a bug. it is clearly a bug. is there anyone can give us the solution

Answer (score 3):

You can bind a session to IP address using a custom filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    boolean chainCompleted = implementEnforcement(request, response);
    if (!chainCompleted) {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

private boolean implementEnforcement(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    final String key = "enforcement.ip";
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (session != null) {
        // we have a session
        String ip = request.getRemoteAddr();
        String ipInSession = session.getAttribute(key);
        if (ipInSession == null) {
            session.setAttribute(key, ip);
        } else {
            if (!ipInSession.equals(ip)) {
                // JSESSIONID is the same, but IP has changed
                // invalidate the session because there is a probability that it is
                // a session hijack
                session.invalidate();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

It remembers user's IP address and then compares current IP with the remembered one: if it differs, the session is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Spring security `hasIpAddress()` check spring security [refrence](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I think I'll just stick to storing the original IP in the session. I guess the docs you referred to is something I should've studied further nonetheless, thanks for the reminder.